# How can I have Solgema.fullcalendar, plone.app.event and plone.app.contenttypes to work together?

Tags: events, fullcalendar, plone, dexterity

On a fresh new Plone 4.3.2, I have installed these 3 products:

```
plone.app.contenttypes (1.1a1)
plone.app.event (1.0.4, with the dexterity and ploneintegration extras)
Solgema.fullcalendar (2.3.2)
```

From my policy product metadata.xml I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<metadata>
    <version>1</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>profile-plone.app.dexterity:default</dependency>
        <dependency>profile-plone.app.contenttypes:default</dependency>
        <dependency>profile-plone.app.event:default</dependency>
        <dependency>profile-plone.app.event.ploneintegration:default</dependency>
        <dependency>profile-Solgema.fullcalendar:default</dependency>
    </dependencies>
</metadata>
```

Now, the issue is, when I install everything I:

- Create a folder
- Go to that folder, and apply the "Solgema Fullcalendar" view, which renders the calendar just fine.
- Click on any date to try and add a new event, and I get the following error

  Traceback (innermost last):

  - Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 138, in publish
  - Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  - Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 48, in call_object
  - Module Products.CMFFormController.FSControllerPythonScript, line 107, in __call__
  - Module Products.CMFFormController.ControllerBase, line 231, in getNext
  - Module Products.CMFFormController.Actions.TraverseTo, line 38, in __call__
  - Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  - Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 48, in call_object
  - Module Solgema.fullcalendar.browser.dx, line 38, in __call__
  - Module Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile, line 125, in __call__
  - Module Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile, line 59, in __call__
  - Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 132, in pt_render
  - Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 240, in __call__
  - Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 271, in __call__
  - Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  - Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 888, in do_useMacro
  - Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  - Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  - Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  - Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  - Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  - Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 852, in do_condition
  - Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  - Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  - Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  - Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  - Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  - Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 946, in do_defineSlot
  - Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  - Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  - Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  - Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  - Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  - Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 620, in do_insertText_tal
  - Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 225, in evaluateText
  - Module zope.tales.tales, line 696, in evaluate
    **URL: /trabajo/buildout/eggs/Solgema.fullcalendar-2.3.2-py2.7.egg/Solgema/fullcalendar/browser/edit_dx_event.pt**
    **Line 9, Column 0**
    **Expression: <StringExpr u" sf_goto_date='${view/isodate}'">**
    **Names:**

    ```
    {'args': (),
     'container': <Event at /Plone/my-events/portal_factory/Event/event.2013-12-13.7249633222 used for /Plone/my-events>,
     'context': <Event at /Plone/my-events/portal_factory/Event/event.2013-12-13.7249633222 used for /Plone/my-events>,
     'default': <object object at 0x7f0fa971db80>,
     'here': <Event at /Plone/my-events/portal_factory/Event/event.2013-12-13.7249633222 used for /Plone/my-events>,
     'loop': {},
     'nothing': None,
     'options': {},
     'repeat': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.SafeMapping object at 0x7f0f909c2a48>,
     'request': <HTTPRequest, URL=http://localhost:8080/Plone/my-events/createSFEvent>,
     'root': <Application at >,
     'template': <Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile.ViewPageTemplateFile object at 0xbd1f190>,
     'traverse_subpath': [],
     'user': <PropertiedUser 'admin'>,
     'view': <Products.Five.metaclass.InlineFrameEditForm object at 0x7f0f98696c90>,
     'views': <Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile.ViewMapper object at 0x7f0f900e1610>}
    ```
  - Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 383, in __call__
  - Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 225, in evaluateText
  - Module zope.tales.tales, line 696, in evaluate
    **URL: /trabajo/buildout/eggs/Solgema.fullcalendar-2.3.2-py2.7.egg/Solgema/fullcalendar/browser/edit_dx_event.pt**
    **Line 9, Column 0**
    **Expression: <PathExpr path:u'view/isodate'>**
    **Names:**

    ```
    {'args': (),
     'container': <Event at /Plone/my-events/portal_factory/Event/event.2013-12-13.7249633222 used for /Plone/my-events>,
     'context': <Event at /Plone/my-events/portal_factory/Event/event.2013-12-13.7249633222 used for /Plone/my-events>,
     'default': <object object at 0x7f0fa971db80>,
     'here': <Event at /Plone/my-events/portal_factory/Event/event.2013-12-13.7249633222 used for /Plone/my-events>,
     'loop': {},
     'nothing': None,
     'options': {},
     'repeat': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.SafeMapping object at 0x7f0f909c2a48>,
     'request': <HTTPRequest, URL=http://localhost:8080/Plone/my-events/createSFEvent>,
     'root': <Application at >,
     'template': <Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile.ViewPageTemplateFile object at 0xbd1f190>,
     'traverse_subpath': [],
     'user': <PropertiedUser 'admin'>,
     'view': <Products.Five.metaclass.InlineFrameEditForm object at 0x7f0f98696c90>,
     'views': <Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile.ViewMapper object at 0x7f0f900e1610>}
    ```
  - Module zope.tales.expressions, line 217, in __call__
  - Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 155, in _eval
  - Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 117, in render
  - Module Solgema.fullcalendar.browser.dx, line 43, in isodate

  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isoformat'

Has anyone experience with these 3 products together? am I missing some configuration ?

I tried to follow the execution for the Solgema.fullcalendar product, and I reach the part were Solgema/fullcalendar/skins/solgemafullcalendar/createSFEvent.cpy is called, and under line 33, it calls SFAjax_base_edit, and this view fails, because this event doesn't have any date set yet.

Being that I'm creating a new event, shouldn't this be calling SFAjax_add_dx_event instead ?

Anyway, a bit lost here, any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be a bug and probably is already reported with: https://github.com/collective/Solgema.fullcalendar/issues/29 . If you want, you can leave a note there, that you are experiencing this issue, too.

Comment: Did you, by any chance, have fixed this already with https://github.com/collective/Solgema.fullcalendar/pull/17 ?

Comment: I have a note to self after the PloneConf / ScalingMountains talk to use ftw.calendar instead of Solgema.fullcalendar. Have you tried that?

Comment: Argh, sorry didn't realise this Qu was from last year!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is most likely already fixed in recent Solgema.fullcalendar versions. I cannot reproduce the error with a current setup on Plone 4.3.4.1. I'm using these version fixes in my buildout:

```
[versions]
plone.app.event = 1.1.4
plone.app.contenttypes = 1.1b3
Solgema.fullcalendar = 2.3.4
```

Please note, that you do not need the `profile-plone.app.event.ploneintegration:default` profile anymore.